# How to overlay (partially transparent) <a-sky />, like doing that to <img />?

Tags: aframe

We are building a tool for 3D view of home decoration, customers can click on a sofa and it will show or hide in the 3D view.

They provide me panorama images of the home background, and a sofa image of the same size but transparent except the sofa part.

I tried:

```
<a-sky src='background.jpg' />
<a-sky src='sofa.jpg' />
```

expecting them to overlay. But sofa image block the background, despite being transparent. More specifically the result is a sofa in empty white space, rather than a sofa in the given background(which is desired result).

How am I going to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

`jpg` format does not support transparency. Use `png` instead.

Set `material:transparent` property to `true` on sofa entity.

```
<a-sky src='sofa.png' material="transparent:true" />
```

Below is a working fiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/od6gxgyL/1/

> As a side note, A-Frame is adding grey border around the opaque part
>   of png image. Unable to figure out why this is happening. I would be glad to know if anyone has solved this issue.